# nginx status вернуть 426

Tags: nginx

Надо в конфиге nginx на все запросы вернуть файл json и установить статус кода в 426,
в директории собственно сам файл 426.json,

конф локейшина:

```
    location / {
        root /home/bitrix;
        try_files $uri $uri /426.json =426;
    }
```

при таком локейшине на все запросы возвращает нужный json, но статус кода всегда 200 ok,
можно ли вернуть статус кода 426?

Comment: `location / { error_page 426 /426.json; return 426; } location /426.json {}`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! помогло. )

Comment: @AlexeyTen, оформите в виде ответа - я проголосую)) Я думал дубликат найти подобной истории но не нашел

Comment: На Stackoverflow не принято говорить "спасибо" ни ответом, ни комментарием. Обратите внимание сюда [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам правда нужно на **любой** запрос отвечать одним и тем же файлом с кодом `426`, то проще всего сделать так:

```
root /home/bitrix;

location / {
    error_page 426 @426;
    return 426;
}

location @426 {
    # просто отдаём файл
    rewrite ^ /426.json break;
}
```

Поправил по сравнению с комментарием, что бы действительно любой запрос получал 426. В примере из комментария запрос за `/426.json` получит ответ 200.

Comment: Действительно на все запросы возвращает код 426 вместе с файлом 426.json. Cпасибо огромное!